# Group events by sequence, defining the minimum period between sequences t-SQL

Tags: t-sql

I have a table of events, called `tbl_events` that looks something like this:

```
PersonID    Date
1           30/03/2015
1           22/04/2015
1           30/06/2015
2           18/07/2016
2           09/12/2016
2           28/04/2017
3           01/10/2014
3           28/11/2016
3           28/11/2016
3           16/01/2017
4           13/04/2017
4           09/05/2017
```

I want to be able to group these events up by the start date of each 'sequence', with a sequence being defined as a run of events from the first identified to the last identified for each PersonID. The last event in a sequence is defined as the event where thereafter there are no subsequent events for that PersonID for a year.

The result of this I would expect to look like is below:

```
PersonID    FirstDate   Sequence    Events
1           30/03/2015  1           3
2           18/07/2016  1           3
3           01/10/2014  1           1
3           28/11/2016  2           3
4           13/04/2017  1           2
```

I am able to identify the sequences in Excel and pivot the data, but I need to be able to do this in SQL.

Here is the formula I have used in Excel to generate the sequence number (I am populating cell C3, with column A being PersonID and B being Date):

```
=+IF(A2<>A3,1,IF((B3-B2)<365,C2,C2+1))
```

I have joined the table back on itself using `ROW_NUMBER` to get the difference between the Date and the previous event date for that ID, but I'm not really sure where to go from there.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you working with?

Comment: SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0):

My solution is based on the sample data you've provided along with your excel formula.

```
-- easily consumable sample data
DECLARE @tbl_events TABLE (PersonId int, [date] date)
INSERT @tbl_events VALUES
(1,'20150330'),(1,'20150422'),(1,'20150630'),(2,'20160718'),(2,'20161209'),(2,'20170428'),
(3,'20141001'),(3,'20161128'),(3,'20161128'),(3,'20170116'),(4,'20170413'),(4,'20170509');

-- Solution
WITH groupings AS
(
  SELECT 
    PersonId, 
    FirstDate = MIN([date]) OVER (PARTITION BY personId ORDER BY [date]),
    NextDate  = LAG([date],1,[date]) OVER (PARTITION BY personId ORDER BY [date]),
    [date],
    grouper   = 
      DATEDIFF(DAY, MIN([date]) OVER (PARTITION BY personId ORDER BY [date]), [date]) / 365
  FROM @tbl_events
),
Prep AS
(
  SELECT 
    PersonId, 
    firstDate = IIF(grouper = 0, FirstDate, IIF(FirstDate = NextDate, [date],NextDate))
  FROM groupings
)
SELECT 
  PersonId, 
  FirstDate, 
  [Sequence] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY personId ORDER BY FirstDate),
  [Events] = COUNT(*)
FROM prep
GROUP BY personId, FirstDate;
```

**Results**

```
PersonId    FirstDate  Sequence             Events
----------- ---------- -------------------- -----------
1           2015-03-30 1                    3
2           2016-07-18 1                    3
3           2014-10-01 1                    1
3           2016-11-28 2                    3
4           2017-04-13 1                    2
```

First note all years have 365 days, nonetheless, I'm using 365 to emulate your excel logic; this would need to be updated to account for leap years. Next, like your excel formula - this will only be correct when there are two sequences;
it would not work when, say personId has a date of jan 1 2015, then jan 10 2016, then feb 1 2017.Let us know if we need logic to accommodate for the aforementioned scenarios.

Lastly this solution uses LAG which requires SQL Server 2012+, if you're working with an earlier version of SQL the query will have to be updated accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Alan, this looks promising, although there will most definitely be PersonID's with more than 2 sequences in the data. The Excel formula I provided currently works - it adds 1 to the previous sequence number if the period between the two events is more than 365 days (I'm not bothered about leap years), so there is no limit to the number of sequences per PersonID. I'm using SQL Server 2008.